# How to implement try-catch block in racket?

Tags: exception, try-catch, lisp, racket

I try to write a `try-catch` block in racket, from the boilerplate provided [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/try-catch/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._try-catch%2Fmain..rkt%29._try%29%29), however when I run it throws me an error.

`try-catch` block:

```
#lang racket
 (require try-catch-match)


(try [(displayln "body")
    (raise 'boom)]
   [catch (string? (printf "caught a string: ~v\n" e))
          (symbol? (printf "'e' (the value of the exception) is: ~v\n" e))])
```

**Throws this error:**

[image]

It says syntax error, but I really cannot see any issues. The code is from the [official racket website](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Lists__Iteration__and_Recursion.html). My goal is to write a simple `try-catch` block in racket, presumably using the imported library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're requiring [try-catch-match](https://docs.racket-lang.org/try-catch-match/index.html) library, but your example comes from [try-catch](https://docs.racket-lang.org/try-catch/index.html) library. These two are different and if you use the correct one, the example code will work:

```
#lang racket
(require try-catch)

(try [(displayln "body")
        (raise 'boom)]
       [catch (string? (printf "caught a string\n"))
              (symbol? (printf "caught a symbol\n"))])
```